# disable lines in RegionPlot when set is not bounded

Tags: plotting

Im trying to plot a horizontal strip in the (x,y)-plane with -1 < y < 1. I achieved this:

```
RegionPlot[
   y^2 <= 1, 
   {x, -2, 2}, 
   {y, -2, 2}, 
   Frame -> False, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[Medium], Dashed], 
   Axes -> True,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
]
```

[image]

As you can see I used dashed lines for the boundary. However mathematica draws this dashed line also at the left and right boundaries but theoretically my set is unbounded to the left and right. I would like to keep the lines on the top and on the bottm, but loosing them left and right.

Comment: Not a great idea, but reducing horizontal `PlotRange` to `PlotRange -> {{-1.99,1.99},{-2,2}}` cutts off left/right border.

Answer (score 3):

```
RegionPlot[y^2 <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Frame -> False, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{-1, 1}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Dashed, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work for this example. Plotting the unit circle will end up having no dashed lines at all.

Comment: @Arjihad, the combination `MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}` and
 ` Mesh -> {{-1, 1}}` works for the specific case in your post. It does not work for all predicates in the first argument of `RegionPlot`.   You need to make changes to the `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` option values based on the region in the first argument of `RegionPlot`.